# MFC/WIN32/C++: How to dispatch messages while doing a computationally intensive operation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc

I would prefer to see if there is a reasonable way to handle this without using a second thread due to the specifics of this application (originally a DOS app with lots of global static variables, converted to Windows/MFC, but not designed from the ground up to be multi-threaded - just making it multiple document aware was a major undertaking).

The application in question is trying to do a very computationally intensive operation which has the side-effect of modifying the current document.  It wants to be able to update the main window & document windows iteratively as the process is performed.

Doing the simple approach: loop through the work-items, issuing drawing on the document's window, modifying the document's underlying data, and updating the status bar with status text indicating x of y complete usually works.  But sometimes the app stops updating both the status bar and the document's window (view) until the entire job is completed, and then everything updates at once.

So there aren't any hang-conditions in the code.  i.e. it never fails to complete.  It's purely a matter of failing to process window messages for the duration (since this is a single threaded application, for the most part).

I thought the obvious approach would be to put a PeekMessage() loop within the task-loop to dispatch any accumulated messages.  I was assuming that this is the reason that the visual updates stop occurring: there must be a windows message in either the view's, the main-frame's, or the thread's message queue blocking the direct updates to the screen.

However, perhaps the issue is something else?

Regardless, it just seems like a bad idea for our app to ignore the message queue for what can be eons of processing time (the user will perceive the app as "stopped responding" if they ask Task Manager just due to the lack of processing our message queue).

However, the following loop becomes infinite:

```
    // dispatch the messages until we're out of them again...
    for (MSG msg; PeekMessage(&msg, NULL,  0, 0, PM_REMOVE); )
    {
        TraceMessage(msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            return;
    }
```

NOTE: TraceMessage() simply outputs a human-friendly trace to the debugger window of what message & arguments this is.  In this case, it is WM_PAINT.

So the paint message, even though it's being requested to be removed, seems to sit in the queue forever (or new ones are being generated somehow infinitely).

---

Questions:

1. Could I have it all wrong, and the reason our applications stops being able to update the status bar & view is something else?
2. Is there a better approach to a long cpu or disk I/o intensive operation than placing a PeekMessage loop within the task loop (that doesn't involve re-architecting the entire application to be more multi-thread-friendly)?

---

Solution I'm going with...

```
void DoSomethingLengthy()
{
    CWaitCursor wait;

    // disable our application windows much as if we were running a modal dialog
    // in order to lock out the user from interacting with us until we're doing doing this thing
    AfxGetMainWnd()->BeginModalState();

    while (bMoreWorkToDo)
    {
        // empty any generated / received thread & window messages
        for (MSG msg; PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE|PM_NOYIELD); ) 
            AfxPumpMessage();

        // for some reason, our cursor reverts to the normal pointer
        // so force ourselves to continue to have the wait-cursor until we're really done
        AfxGetMainWnd()->RestoreWaitCursor();


        // here's where we do one work-item
        // ...
    }

    // restore our prior state
    AfxGetMainWnd()->EndModalState();
}
```

Yes, this is very old technology, and not necessarily the best approach.  It is however feasible and highly useful for this context.  We already have a complex app that uses the OnIdle mechanic for a multitude of purposes, making it less attractive as a possible approach.

Comment: I have two possible solutions that seem to work, but I'm still uncertain that they're (either one) complete / sound solutions:
 for (MSG msg; PeekMessage(&msg, NULL,  0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE); )
 {
  TraceMessage(msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
  AfxPumpMessage();
 }

Comment: Alternately I can successfully use: for (MSG msg; PeekMessage(&msg, NULL,  0, 0, PM_REMOVE|PM_NOYIELD); ) { if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) return; DispatchMessage(&msg); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PeekMessage` only looks ahead at the next message. You want `GetMessage` to remove it from the queue, and then `DispatchMessage` to actually invoke `WndProc`.

At this point you just reinvented `DoEvents` from VB, the staple of 1996 technology.

Comment: I can add a DispatchMessage() to the loop-body, and that does seem to drain the message queue.  But am I now looking at problems because I'm not doing TranslateMessage, and I'm circumventing the MFC PreTranslateMessage mechanics (and their entire message dispatching framework)?...

Answer (score 2):

The reason your app won't update is because nothing is processing the WM_PAINT messages. WM_PAINT is unique in that it is generated on demand, whenever Windows determines that parts of a window are out of date. That's why you get an infinite number of them.

The best solution is to break your long task into pieces, and use PostMessage to place a custom message into the queue that you can use to continue where you left off.

Comment: I thought about doing this.  Due to the way that this application works, it's possible but a fairly big pain to break this up.  And it would be nice not to be forced to exit the current message handler over & over.  It would be quite nice to act as a sort of modal activity dispatching messages until this loop is done.  So I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve exiting the current handler, but rather building a modal inner-message-dispatch-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out that WM_PAINT is normally synthesized when needed, rather than there ever actually being a WM_PAINT message in the message queue.

Getting to your real problem, it seems to me that there are really only two real possibilities: either re-architect it, or leave it alone. If you're going to leave it alone, it's probably best to just isolate it, so your application runs in two almost completely separate pieces: one is your nearly-unchanged DOS application, doing things just as it always has. The other is a GUI front end that's almost completely separate.

Exactly how you do that depends on how the DOS application produces its output. If it uses standard streams (e.g., writing to standard output with printf and such) it's probably easiest to convert it to a Win32 console application. Have your GUI application spawn the console application, and redirect its standard input, standard output and standard error streams into anonymous pipes to the parent. The parent GUI application will then (for example) read data as it comes in on the child's standard output, and update your GUI accordingly.

If, OTOH, you have a "full screen" DOS program that was written to use the screen buffer directly, then it's a bit easier to keep it as part of the same application in the GUI. In a typical case, such a program will have some code that retrieves a pointer to the screen, and then treats that as a 2D array of character/attribute pairs. To "trap" its output, you substitute an array of your own in place of the hardware screen buffer. From there you have two choices. If the original code is written in C++ (or C that's compatible with C++) your virtual screen buffer can overload some operators to notify you want changes take place. Otherwise, you can poll it every (say) 100 ms, and (for example) hash the contents to determine whether it's changed so you need to update your GUI. While polling never *sounds* like a good idea, hashing 8K of data at 100 ms intervals isn't really likely to cause a major problem.

I'll repeat though: at least IMO, there are only two choices that are likely to work out well: Either cleanly integrate the code by re-architecting as needed to let it run nicely in a thread, or else cleanly separate the code by architecting a clean communication between the computation and the GUI. At least IME, halfway points between those extremes *rarely* work out well. You need to either separate or integrate the code, but either way you need to do it thoroughly and cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

`WM_PAINT` is synthesized whenever the queue is empty and there is a non-empty invalid region.  To stop `WM_PAINT` messages, you have to mark the window area valid.  That happens during `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` in the normal course of paint processing.

When [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213.aspx) says "After an internal WM_PAINT message is returned from GetMessage or PeekMessage or is sent to a window by UpdateWindow, the system does not post or send further WM_PAINT messages until the window is invalidated or until RedrawWindow is called again with the RDW_INTERNALPAINT flag set.", that assumes that the message was completely processed.  If you fail to abide by the contract of `WM_PAINT` processing (call `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`, among other things) then the "no more WM_PAINT messages" behavior can't be relied on either.

Comment: D'oh!  Of course it's generating a WM_PAINT as soon as I empty out the other messages. :P